# How to use setVisibility on integer array in adapter list view by onclick on ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, onclick, adapter, invisible

I'm trying to invisible an image when it is clicked by storing images from drawable into integer array using adapter list view, but I'm unable to get it. This is the code I'm using:

When i click on an image it should get invisible.I am storing images in int array and applying setVisibilty invisible but its not working.i want an image to be displayed in centre of screen and the one which is clicked should get invisible.i am trying to store images in an integer array and setting it up in adapter list.i am calling this function

> imageIDs[position].setVisible(false);

```
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
                R.drawable.c2,
                R.drawable.c3,
                R.drawable.c4,
                R.drawable.c5,
                R.drawable.c6,
                R.drawable.c7,
                R.drawable.c8
        };
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Note that Gallery view is deprecated in Android 4.1---
            Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
            //Adapter list
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            //onclick event              
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
                {//displaying image clicked i am trying to invisible this pic when click
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",//dispplpaying msg
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //imageIDs[position].setVisible(false);
                    // display the images selected
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
                    //setting image on screen from using xml 
                }
            });
        }
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;
            private int itemBackground;
            public ImageAdapter(Context c)
            {
                context = c;
                // sets a grey background; wraps around the images
                TypedArray a =obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyGallery);
                itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
                a.recycle();
            }
            // returns the number of images
            public int getCount() {
                return imageIDs.length;
            }
            // returns the ID of an item
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            // returns the ID of an item
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            // returns an ImageView view
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
                //imageIDs[position].setVisible(false);
                //i am trying it here but its not working
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
                return imageView;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: where is the code that is not working that you need help on? who is that image, if you want to invisible an image why not `ImageView.setVisibility(1);` elaborate sir

Comment: @Elltz i have edited question with a screen shot as im trying  to invisbile an image from Top list shown in **screen shot**  and displaying it in centre

Comment: im always late to the party, guess u have sloved it. yu can also save the ids of the image in the array & use it, thats just btw

Comment: hahah nope, not solved yet.still trying

Comment: so update me what are you trying now ?

Comment: above mentioned problem is solved by calling v.setVisibility(View.GONE) now i trying to arrange the Adapter list as one image is gone. I don't want to show this blank can i shift this list to fill the blank place.if yes, then How ?

Comment: can you create a chat sir, so we solve your problem there.

Comment: well, i'm new here in Stack Over flow and don't know about creation of CHAT.

Comment: okay, i created my personal chat [extended help](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77204/extended-help) come place your additional questions there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to use this code:

```
//imageIDs[position].setVisible(false);
```

If so then what you're doing is calling setVisible on an Integer, which does not have that method. What you need to do is get a reference to the ImageView in which the image is being displayed and then call setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or setVisibility(View.GONE) on it.

Also it seems like you're trying to set the image to invisible but then you go and put the same resource back into the ImageView so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Mr. @spacitron  yeah. i know that  i'm calling setVisible on an Integer, the problem is that i tried a lot to get ImageView reference but failed logically.

I'm making a card game in which if an image is click should get invisible and virtually connected players will be notified by broadcasting a msg.

Comment: In onItemClick the ImageView is passed in as the View v parameter. Call v.setVisibility(View.GONE) there.

Comment: let me try like this.

Comment: o yeah its working champ.Thanks a million.Now can i shift back the images as one image is gone after clicked.